# Heroku PS:Exec with ENV Vars

Tags: heroku

**I see this in the Heroku docs:**

The SSH session created by Heroku Exec will not have the config vars set as environment variables (i.e., env in a session will not list config vars set by heroku config:set).

I need to be able to SSH into our sidekiq container specifically and run a console session there. To do this, I need access to the ENV vars. I cannot do this in a one off bash container, because the config is different for sidekiq container, and I need to confirm that values are getting set properly (via the console).

Something like this:
`heroku ps:exec -a [our-app] -d [sidekiq.1] --with-env-vars`

How can I use `heroku ps:exec` (or a similar command) to ssh into an existing dyno WITH config vars present?

Answer (score 0):

No the most ideal, but there is an option which is helpful for me.

**Identify the command call**

This is to identify the potential process that will contain the environment variables.

`ps auxfww` that will give you a result similar to:

```bash
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
nobody       1  0.0  0.0   6092  3328 ?        Ss   18:19   0:00 ps-run
u19585       4  0.5  0.6 553984 410984 ?       Sl   18:19   0:19 puma 4.3.12 (tcp://0.0.0.0:36152) [app]
u19585      26  0.0  0.0   9836  2248 ?        S    18:19   0:00  \_ bash --login -c bundle exec puma -p 36152 -C ./config/puma.rb
```

In this case `bash --login -c bundle exec puma` will be our ENV Process picker.

**Load your ENV variables**

Then run the `source` command to call the ENVS each time you get connected through `ps:exec`

```bash
source <(cat /proc/$(pgrep -f "bash --login -c bundle exec puma")/environ | strings)
```

- `source <(<DATA>)`: export your variables in a call
- `pgrep -f "<IDENTIFIED_COMMAND>"`: picks the PID
- `cat /proc/<PID>/environ`: contains the app env variables
- `strings`: to convert the 'binary' lines to string lines

After that, you'll have your main ENV variables available in your console.

Finally copy in a good place your `source` call to use it when you need it.